# How can I read/write from/to a file, byte by byte, with PHP5?

Tags: php, file, binary

I've worked with reading and writing text files with PHP.  Now, I'd like to read and write binary files.  I've not found any useful resources/tutorials for doing this with PHP5.  Is it possible?  How?

Specifically, I'll be searching for specific 2-byte patterns.

If it matters, I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.4 Tiger).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) your binary with 'b' (for binary) attached to the mode parameter. Reading from the stream is done by [fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). PHP offers the common binary operators for manipulating your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use f`open("filename.ext", "rb")` under Windows. Which OS are you interested in?

Anyway you can find information about binary files in PHP5 documentation for function [fopen](https://www.php.net/function.fopen).